# getServerSideProps vs fetching directly in React

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am getting a bit confused with the getServerSideProps of NextJS.

In the docs you can find this explanation.

> For example, suppose that your page needs to pre-render frequently
> updated data (fetched from an external API). You can write
> getServerSideProps which fetches this data and passes it to Page

My confusing is why would you use getServerSideProps if you could simply fetch the data every x sec in your React component itself (after getting the initials data via getStaticProps).

Is there an advantage of using getServerSideProps over just the React way ?

so like this for example :

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const interval=setInterval(()=>{
      const fetchdata = async () => {
        const res = await fetch("url")
        const data = await res.json()
        setsongs(data)
      }
      fetchdata()
     },15000)
     return()=>clearInterval(interval)
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to the documentation, `getServerSideProps` fetches the API data on every request. So, there is a difference between requesting with a time interval ( like you mentioned in the react version), or using `getServerSideProps`.
Also, remember that `getServerSideProps` is implemented on the server-side and might be useful in cases that SEO is important. However, if the server goes down in the cases that you use `getServerSideProps` the whole page would not be served anymore.
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

Meanwhile, Fetching data on the client side (or the React way) is useful when SEO is not relevant, the page doesn’t need to be pre-rendered.
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fetching-data-on-the-client-side

In my opinion, it would be better if you use `getServerSideProps` when the displayed data is changing frequently and the user should see the most updated one, SEO is vital and a longer Time to first byte (TTFB) is acceptable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I do not exactly get, why would I use getServerSideProps if I can just use getStaticProps when pre-rendering the page and afterwards fetch every x seconds on the client side via React ? SEO will still be good because the initial load has the correct tags with it ( those will not change when react re-renders the component)

Answer (score 0):

There are useCases for all of them. You can use useEffect if SEO is not a concern and you want data to be updated in real-time.

You can use getServerSideProps when you want to have a better SEO ranking in your page.

Sure You can use getStaticProps which is way faster but know that getStaticProps is best used if your page contents don't change and stay the same like in a e-commerce website's product detail page.